# How to add description like: "Comments for paragraph 1" to comments

Tags: comments

I have written a module that allows users to put comment on each paragraph. So in comment form there is a field that asks the user which paragraph do they want to put comment on. 
I have to mention that I have added a column to my comment table, which saves that paragraph number.

```
function Annotations_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$form['paragraph_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Which paragraph you want to put comment on?'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 2,
    '#default_value' => !empty($form['#entity']->paragraph_id) ? $form['#entity']-   >paragraph_id : NULL, // set the default value to the current paragraph value
     '#weight' => $form['subject']['#weight'] + 1, // place after the subject   field by setting the weight to +1 of subject weight
);

$form['#validate'][] = 'annotations_form_comment_form_validate';
$form['#submit'][] = 'annotations_form_comment_form_submit';

 }
```

I also have Annotations_form_comment_form_validate  and Annotations_form_comment_form_submit functions for validation and submitting.

I have also written the following code to sort the comments based on the number of the paragraph. So first you see the comments on paragraph 1, and then 2, etc.

```
    <?php

  define('COMMENT_SORT_OLDER_FIRST', 1); // default
  define('COMMENT_SORT_Paragraph', 2);
 /* Alter node type form: allow user to decide comments sorting */
  function Annotations_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['comment']['comment_default_sorting'] = array(
 '#title' => t('Sort'),
 '#type' => 'select',
 '#options' => array(1 => t('Older first'), 
                     2 => t('Paragraph Number')),
 '#default_value' => variable_get('comment_default_sorting_' . $form['#node_type']->type, COMMENT_SORT_OLDER_FIRST), 
 );
  }


  /* Alter comments query */
 function Annotations_query_comment_filter_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query){
  if ( ($node = $query->getMetaData('node')) && (get_class($query) == 'PagerDefault')             ) {
  $sort = variable_get('comment_default_sorting_' . $node->type,              COMMENT_SORT_OLDER_FIRST);
    if ($sort == COMMENT_SORT_Paragraph) {
  $orderby =& $query->getOrderBy();  
  $expressions =& $query->getExpressions();
  if (isset($orderby['torder'])) { 
      unset($expressions['torder']);
      unset($orderby['torder']);
      $orderby['c.paragraph_id'] = 'ASC';
  } else {
    $orderby['c.cid'] = 'DESC';
    }
   }
 }
}
```

I want to have a line like: " Comments on Paragraph 1 " and then show the comments for paragraph 1, and the same for rest of the comments.

Does anybody know how can I do that  or which hooks I can use? Do you know some other modules or examples that do something similar, so it will give me some idea that how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will **really** be answerable without the code you wrote.

General answer is:

1. alter query that gets comments to include paragraph number ([`hook_query_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7))
2. alter their rendering, so paragraph number is sent to .tpl files ([`hook_comment_view_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_view_alter/7))
3. change tpl file of your theme to display that number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edit my questions and added my code. So do you know what hooks I should use to alter the way that comments are displayed? or how can I do that?